# Why doesn't It not worked? android recyclerView refresh

Tags: android, fragment, refresh, android-recyclerview

I make a recyclerview Adapter.
and I fetch data from my server using AsyncTask.
I used Retrofit API, and I coded Callback func();
 When data successfully are fetched from server, I will refresh RecyclerView Adapter. So I use notifyDataSetChanged() . But no refreshed..
I checked the fetched data precisely. RecyclerView was placed in fragment. 
Why doesn't work?

Comment: Are you sure, that you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` in the UI thread?

Comment: Yeah. I used UI thread.....Ah. I used FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: I placed recyclerview and recycler adapter in A fragment. When MainActivity started, this fragment is activate and I request data to server using asyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can place this code in your method that you call for refreshing

```
     Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    getActivity().finish();

    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
```

It basically refreshes the activity and hence the recyclerview is also refreshed